# Is my fabric code actually multithreading?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, fabric, gevent

I am attempting to get a **multi-threaded solution using gevent** for a set of tasks, some of which use the **fabric api**. When trying to monkeypatch, fabric fails to read env and prompts for password. When not patching everything works, but the execution does not appear to be asynchronous. I created the following *toy example* for this question:

```
from gevent import monkey, spawn, sleep, joinall
monkey.patch_socket()  # If removed, "appears to" runs serial
from fabric.api import run, env, settings

import os

env.use_ssh_config = True
env.host_string = "user@remotehost"
env.user = "user"
env.key_filename = os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/id_rsa_4096')
env.password = ""
env.port = 22

def toyTask(char):
    command = "ls %s*" %char
    print command
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        run(command)
    sleep()

charList = list(map(chr,range(97,123))) # Creates ['a','b',...........'z']
threads = [spawn(toyTask, char) for char in charList]
joinall(threads)
```

In its current form, this returns:

> me@localhost:~$ python gevent_fab.py
>   ls a*
>   [user@remotehost] run: ls a*
>   ls b*
>   [user@remotehost] run: ls b*
>   ls c*
>
> ..
>
> ..
>
> [user@remotehost] run: ls z*
>   ls z*
>
> No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"
>   [user@remotehost] **Login password for 'user'**:

If `monkey.patch_socket` is removed, fabric no longer prompts for password and returns the expected output as follows:

> ls a*
>   [user@remotehost] run: ls a*
>   [user@remotehost] out: kegg.csh  kegg.pl
>   [user@remotehost] out:
>
> ls b*
>   [user@remotehost] run: ls b*
>   [user@remotehost] out: bin:
>   [user@remotehost] out: afiedt.buf         hash_mod.py-orig   renamePat.pl
>
> ls c*
>
> ..
>
> ..
>
> ls z*
>   [user@remotehost] run: ls z*
>   [user@remotehost] out: ls: cannot access z*: No such file or directory
>   [user@remotehost] out

### My questions are:

1. Is my code parallelizing the toyTask at all although the output
    appears serial?
2. Why does fabric prompt for password when calling
    `monkey.patch_socket()`?

Comment: what's wrong with using the existing parallel execution provided in fabric?

Comment: The actual task I am trying to run in parallel is only partly in fabric - The toy example is created only to illustrate the problem. There is a local component that will benefit from general multithreading using gevent or something like that.